# SAS different random number

Tags: random, sas, numbers

In SAS you can generate random numbers using a seed at each data step; same seed in 2 diff data steps = same serie of random number in 2 diff data steps.

is there a trick to have 2 different series of random number from the same seed in 2  different data steps?
Thanks for the tips.

following India Rocket answers: 
I should add that i'm meant to use the same distribution across data step.

One way i found way to create a huge dafile of random number and pick in those at each data step. 
I was wondering if there was something smarter :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:-

```
/*Using same distribution without changing the seed*/

data A(drop=i);
  call streaminit(123);
  do i = 1 to 5;
    col1 = rand("Normal",0,0.83325) + i; output;
  end;
run;


data E(drop=i);
  call streaminit(123);
  do i = 6 to 10;
    col1 = rand("Normal",0,0.83325) + i; output;
  end;
 run;
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Hiya
Thanks for the reply. and you are dead right. 
 Ishould have specified I am using the same distribution (Normal). One way i thought was to generate a huge table of random numbers and pick from that list in my different data steps; It's combursome but would work; I was wondering if there was a cleverer idea :-)

Comment: Hey That I guess is an easier thing to do. Just keep the Distribution same across datasets and change the value of 'i' in my code. For example, instead of 1 to 5, change it 2 to 10 in second dataset. That way you don't need to create a separate dataset and pick the numbers from there.  Thanks :-)

Comment: like so?
it doesn't do the job I'm afraid :-(

data A(drop=i);
  call streaminit(123);
  do i = 1 to 5 ;
    col1 = rand("Normal",0,0.83325) ; output;
  end;
run;
data E(drop=i);
  call streaminit(123);
  do i = 6 to 10 ;
    col1 = rand("Normal",0,0.83325) ; output;
  end;
 run;

Comment: I appreciate your help India Rocket

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add a point about adding 'i' in equation like this:               
col1 = 'rand("Normal",0,0.83325)+ i'.

Comment: OR just add a random number like 100 and 1000 across 2 datasets respectively like this: col1 =rand("Normal",0,0.83325)+ 100; 
col1 = rand("Normal",0,0.83325) + 1000 ; That way we can preserve the distribution with out having the same values.                                                                            Thanks for the feedback @Mr T.   Happy Learning:-)

Comment: @Mr T. You are most welcome. Please upvote/accept if this solution helped you